# Sed regex isn't being as greedy as it ought

Tags: regex, sed

Trying to just let myself know if a wp-config.php file has some particular values in it. In testing I tried to add a copy of the line after a comment:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', firsttrue ); //define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', secondtrue );
```

And the idea is to have sed spit out 'firsttrue'. Here's what I'd been using that worked fine until this test case:

```
sed 's|.*\?,\(.*\?\));.*|\1|'
```

But it just returns 'secondtrue'. Wondering why that is and how to get it to return what I'm after. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that is possible in sed. You might want to add some character classes.

```
sed 's|[^,]*,\([^);]*\));.*|\1|'
```

So you look for as many non-comma characters as you can, so you're guaranteed to match on the first comma, and then return the first string after `,` and before `);`. If you want to also not capture any spaces, add some space character groups.

```
sed 's|[^,]*,\s*\([^);]*\)\s*);.*|\1|'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you user perl?  if so:

```
perl -lne '/.*?,\s+(.*?)\s+\)/ && print $1'
```

Ex:

```
[root@TIAGO-TEST tmp]# cat file
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', firsttrue ); //define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', secondtrue );
[root@TIAGO-TEST tmp]# cat file | perl -lne '/.*?,\s+(.*?)\s+\)/ && print $1'
firsttrue
```

I never managed to get non-greedy match working for sed.

Comment: `sed` only supports BRE and ERE none of which supports non-greedy match. PCRE is the only way to go. I probably would have written `perl -lne 'print $1 for /.*?,\s+(.*?)\s+\)/' file` but +1 none the less.